# Div drop shadow that fades out as you scroll down

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

I am looking for a way to have my main contents div have a drop shadow that fades away as you scroll down the page. The perfect example is at http://www.gamespot.com/ notice their main content has a drop shadow that makes its pop but then slowly goes away making the site look flat. How is this effect achieved? Thanks!

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? I can't see any shadows on GameSpot.com

Comment: Sure. Ill post one now. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, all I see on gamespot is a short gradient background at the top of the page.

Comment: OK ive uploaded a screenshot. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: You can use box-shadow like this box-shadow: 0px -5px 20px -5px 
#999; to container div but first check that your container div is taking full height.

Comment: @SVS That works but i also want the shadow to stop at some point. Your solution right now just continues the shadow as the div grows with more content.

Comment: i didn't get u..stop at some point means??

Comment: You can steal the basic idea from http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-paper-curl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution, as briefly mentioned above in the comments, is to use a gradient drop-shadow as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3eDpM/

The other solution (a more static one) is to use a small image in the background, say, a 2px by 40px gradient produced in photoshop. Then, have that image repeat horizontally in the background of the desired div, while positioning it to the top left. Such as:

```
width: 2px;
height: 40px;
background-position: left top;
background-image: url('../img/gradient.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```